# Search A and replace B in A|B in shell scripting/SED/AWK

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

I have a text file with layout as:

```
tableName1|counterVariable1
tableName2|counterVariable2
```

I want to replace the counterVariable1 with some other variable say counterVariableNew.

How can I accomplish this?

I have tried various SED/AWK approaches, closest one is mentioned below:

```
cat $fileName | grep -w $tableName | sed -i 's/$tableName\|counterVariable/$tableName\|counterVariableNew'
```

But all the 3 commands are not merging properly, please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F'|' -v OFS='|' '/tableName1/ {$2="counterVariableNew"}1' file
tableName1|counterVariableNew
tableName2|counterVariable2
```

This will search for `A (tableName1)` and replace `B (counterVariable1)` to `counterVariableNew`.

Or by using `sed` :

```
sed -r '/tableName1/ s/(^.*\|)(.*)/\1counterVariableNew/g' file
tableName1|counterVariableNew
tableName2|counterVariable2
```

For word bounded search:  Enclose the pattern inside `\<` and `\>` .

```
sed -r '/\<tableName1\>/ s/(^.*\|)(.*)/\1counterVariableNew/g' file
awk -F'|' -v OFS='|' '/\<tableName1\>/ {$2="counterVariableNew"}1' file
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but both the commands are searching tableName1*, in place of that they should only search tableName.

eg..

tableName1|counterVariable1
tableName2|counterVariable2
tableName11|counterVariable11

tableName11 will be replaced when you'll try to replace tableName1

Comment: Thanks PS. It worked just perfect!! Though I need some time to understand it.. :p

Comment: That will fail given various values of `tableName1` and various input file contents since it's doing a regexp search on each line instead of a string search on $1. Also you should mention that `\<` and `\>` are gawk-specific.

Answer (score 2):

Your script is an example of [[ useless use of cat ]](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html). But the key point here is to escape the pipe delimiter which has a special meaning(it stands for OR) when used with awk `FS`. So below script should do

```
# cat 42000479
tableName1|counterVariable1
tableName2|counterVariable2
tableName3|counterVariable2

# awk -F\| '$1=="tableName2"{$2="counterVariableNew"}1' 42000479
tableName1|counterVariable1
tableName2 counterVariableNew
tableName3|counterVariable2
```

An alternate way of doing the same stuff is below

```
# awk -v FS='|' '$1=="tableName2"{$2="counterVariableNew"}1' 42000479
```

Stuff inside the single quote will not be expanded.

Comment: This is the correct approach but remember to set the OFS too: `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} $1=="tableName1"{$2="counterVariableNew"} 1' file`. Btw you're not escaping `|` in the first case because it stands for `or` in awk, you're doing it because it stands for `pipe` in shell. Just quote it to hide it from shell.

Comment: @EdMorton, Thanks for the the latter part of the comment, yes indeed. :)